# I can't imagine she will have arrived yet

Tags: modal-verbs

1. I can't imagine she **would** have arrived yet. [speculation]
2. I can't imagine she **will** have arrived yet. [speculation]

Are they both correct and do they mean the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference in meaning.

Asking "*will* you do [x]" is a direct question that invites a 'yes or no' response, whereas asking "*would* you do [x]" is a hypothetical question that invites a hypothetical answer, perhaps with conditions.

For example:

> - Will you buy a Lexus?
> - I will, when the price goes down. (certain, but with a condition)

> - Would you buy a Lexus?
> - If I had the money, I would. (hypothetical)

"Will she have arrived yet?" suggests that the answer will be either yes, or no - perhaps that time is the only factor in whether her journey is complete.

"*Would* she have arrived yet?" suggests that there may be some *reason* why she would not have - that the person being asked has further insight into the logistics of the journey.

Comment: So "she **would** have arrived yet" is NOT like the result clause of a third conditional: If she had studied, she **would** have passed the exam. Here we know that she did not pass. Instead it implies there is a *possibility* that she **has actually arrived**. Am I right?